# if/else logical in jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I'm trying to ensure that list of objects doesn't null and has at least one item in it. Please tell me what am I doing wrong with the following snippet.

```
<c:if test=" ${ (not empty educations) && (fn:length(educations) ge 1) }">
            <c:forEach items="${educations}" var="edu">
                <div class="educations">                    
                    <label>Position</label><input type="text" name="${ edu.index }"  /><br/>
                    <label>School</label><input type="text" name="${ edu.school }" /><br/>
                    <label>Degree</label><input type="text" name="${ edu.degree }"   /><br/>
                    <label>GPA</label><input type="text" name="${ edu.scored }"   /><br/>
                    <label>Start Date</label><input type="text" name="${ edu.startDate }"   /><br/>
                    <label>End Date</label><input type="text" name="${ edu.endDate }"  /><br/>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>        
        </c:if>
```

I found out it stop right at the if statement by debug, and hmlt tags inside hasn't been rendered even if there's item in educations list

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811626/evaluate-empty-or-null-jstl-c-tags

Comment: Yes. And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103082/jstl-condition-with-multiple-operators already, but still can't figure out what's wrong with my snippet. It looks fine but didn't work properly

Comment: What about it didn't work properly?  I'm not seeing any glaring syntax errors.

Comment: I edited the question. It supposes to render html tags inside, but the output page is blank

Answer (score 1):

Have you included properly for JSTL functions ?

```
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
```

And also add prefix  requestScope before accessing any variables.

```
<c:if test=" ${not empty requestScope.educations}">
        <c:forEach items="${requestScope.educations}" var="edu">
            <div class="educations">                    
                <label>Position</label><input type="text" name="${ edu.index }"  /><br/>
                <label>School</label><input type="text" name="${ edu.school }" /><br/>
                <label>Degree</label><input type="text" name="${ edu.degree }"   /><br/>
                <label>GPA</label><input type="text" name="${ edu.scored }"   /><br/>
                <label>Start Date</label><input type="text" name="${ edu.startDate }"   /><br/>
                <label>End Date</label><input type="text" name="${ edu.endDate }"  /><br/>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>        
</c:if>
```

It would be better if you do only the `empty` check

Your intent is to iterate over the list using  then it may be good to know that it already won't run when the provided items is empty. If the  is directly surrounded by this check, then this check is entirely superfluous.

Comment: Yes. I included it. fn:length function work fine. The only problem is the if statement.

Comment: Have you tried adding requestScope.. check the edit. Add ${} for fincing the length of `educations`

Comment: I fixed it by separate if statement into 2 statement. Thanks you guys for helping

Comment: There is no need for the second condition only empty condition is good to serve your purpose.